# First time writing Javascript properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module

I've been writing Javascript with jQuery for a while, I can make it do what I want, but I've never written anything really reusable or modular. Now it's time for me to take that step and write proper reusable Javascript.

I thought I'd start with something I've implemented countless times, a confirm delete dialog. I want to be able to specify a function to execute on confirm and a function to execute on cancel.

The way I see this working (and this is open to criticism) is to do something like:

```
$(element).confirmDialog(function(){
    // this is the cancel callback
},
function(){
    // this is the confirm callback
});
```

I'd also like the dialog to show based on a data attribute on the link, rather than having to write an `.on('click'...` handler each time, but I don't know how to 'link' the specific `confirmDialog` with the function which handles the `.on('click'...`.

This is really as far as I've got so far. I know that as I want to be able to add the functionality to any element I need to define `confirmDialog()` as `$.fn.confirmDialog = function(){...}`.

Although I can implement the entire thing in an ad-hoc way, I'm unsure as to how to implement this functionality as a clearly defined, loosely coupled reusable module.

Could someone help me get my head around how to structure this module, or provide a link to a very thorough tutorial which is specifically about writing reusable Javascript?

Comment: jquery actually has this type of dialog, why not just have a look at the sources to see how they solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about how to create jQuery plugins at the following links:

> http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291290/How-To-Write-Plugin-in-jQuery

NetTuts videos are particularly useful:

> http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/learn-how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin/